# Unpack a war file to a destination folder

Tags: zip, extract

I know how to simply unzip a zip file to destination folder, just type the following command line in terminal:

```
unzip file.zip -d /folder/destination
```

Obviously -d option points out the destination folder, but I doesn't work for jar command line. Command line '`jar -vxf file.war`' will extract file.war to the current folder, but command line '`jar -vxf file.war -d /folder/destination`' does nothing, which means there is nothing generated under folder destination.

Is it possible to set the destination folder for jar command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jar file is zip file. You can extract it with zip.

Comment: I tried and it solved my problem. Thanks for inspiring me.